# Neo4j Cypher: limiting start nodes following lucene query

Tags: lucene, neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query which starts by finding a list of nodes from an index using a lucene query:

```
START n=node:people("name:ROBERT")
MATCH n--o
RETURN n.name, COLLECT(o.task_name)
```

which gets very slow when the query of the index returns a large number of results. I'd like to limit the number of nodes that are used in the rest of the query - i.e. limit n=node:people("name:ROBERT") to, say, thirty results.

I can't see any obvious way to do this in lucene or Cypher.

I suppose I could split it into two queries e.g.:

START n=node:people("name:ROBERT") RETURN n LIMIT 10

Then execute the second part of the query using the nodes returned, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no, right now there's no better way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can I request that as a potential future feature?

Comment: ...one more question - is there any way to chain the two queries together into one? I'm making requests to the REST api and it seems inefficient to make two separate calls. thanks.

Comment: We've discussed adding LIMIT to the WITH clause - that would solve your first problem. We've also discussed adding UNION to Cypher, which would solve your second use case. Both of these features are still in the planning stage for now though. Sorry.